# How would I import a Sub-Module from a script in the Main Module?

Tags: python

Here is my file structure:

> - Main Directory/
>
>   - Main.py
>   - Module/
>
>     - **init**.py
>     - ExampleScript.py
>     - ExampleScript2.py
>     - SubModule/
>
>       - **init**.py
>       - ExampleScript3.py

The code in Main.py is

```
from Module import * # The error is here
```

which should import everything from the Module folder

in ExampleScript.py and ExampleScript2.py I have

```
import SubModule.ExampleScript3
```

and in ExampleScript3.py I have

```
print("example")
```

the desired output is when I run Main.py I get "example" printed to the console
but, when I run Main.py I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'SubModule' where as when it is ran from ExampleScript1 or 2 it prints the desired output

and yes, I know that running Main.py would print "example" twice.

does anybody know how I can get this to work?

also this is my first question, sorry if I got anything wrong with formatting.

Comment: Please take a look at the Packages documentation (Section 6.4) [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: `from Module.SubModule import ExampleScript3`.